# Angular: How to share an index variable from a custom directive to another?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-directives

I'm trying to share an index variable between two **custom** directives: `ngLoop` and `ngDN`.

**This is the code of ngLoop:**

```
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[ngLoop]'
})
export class NgLoopDirective {

  @Input() set ngLoop(iter_count: number) {
    this.container.clear();
    for (let i=0; i<iter_count; i++) {
      this.container.createEmbeddedView(this.template);
    }
  }

  constructor(private template: TemplateRef<any>,
              private container: ViewContainerRef) {}

}
```

**This is the code of ngDN:**

```
import { Directive, Input, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[ngDN]'
})
export class NgDNDirective {

  @Input() set ngDN(dn: number) {
    this.renderer.setAttribute(this.elRef, 'data-num', dn.toString());
  }

  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}

}
```

**Problem:**

Now, whenever I try how successfully it would work from the html code below

```
<div *ngLoop="products.categories.length; let i = index">
                <a href="#"
                   [ngDN]="i"></a>
            </div>
```

I get an error saying:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
>       at NgDNDirective.set [as ngDN] (ng-dn.directive.ts:9)
>       at updateProp (core.es5.js:11102)
>       at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.es5.js:10794)
>       at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.es5.js:12332)
>       at checkAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:12271)
>       at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:13132)
>       at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.es5.js:13073)
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (HomeComponent.html:38)
>       at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.es5.js:13058)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12238)

from which I understood that the index variable `i` wasn't correctly shared.

What's the correct way to share the index variable?

Comment: Your ngLoop directive needs to export the index value. You don't have anything like that by default. This exists in the default NgForOf directive because it's exported in the directive implementation.

Comment: @AdrianFaciu Okay. But, how can I export it?

Comment: Having a look at how [ngForOf is implemented](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/directives/ng_for_of.ts) could be a good start.

Comment: @AdrianFaciu I do not want to do some kind of c/p, but rather I would like to *learn* how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The desugared form of the syntax you want to achieve is the following.

```
<!-- sugared -->
<div *ngLoop="10; let i = index">
  <a href="#" [ngDN]="i"></a>
</div>

<!-- desugared -->
<ng-template [ngLoop]="10" let-i="index">
  <div>
    <a href="#" [ngDN]="i"></a>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

The `let-i="index"` is called **the context**. You set the context by passing an object as a second argument to `createEmbeddedView`.

That is, in the for-loop, you do the following.

```
for (let i = 0; i < iter_count; i++) {
  this.container.createEmbeddedView(this.template, {
    index: i,
  });
}
```

This means that variable `index` will be available in the `ng-template`. By saying `let-i="index"`, you assign the `index` value of that template to a local variable `i`, available only inside the `ng-template` in the template.

A [**demo** is here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stack-overflow-45945305). Open the console and you shall see the numbers.

---

You'll have problems with the renderer though, as the element is not yet available for styling when the input's setter is called. You need to defer it to `AfterViewInit`. But you can `console.log` and comment out your renderer method for now to see that the above does work indeed.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I understood and I tried my best to get it working, but without success -- I get the same error. This is about the code update: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QMJqzO.

Comment: I'm not sure how to run Angular in Codepen. Try StackBlitz. [Here's a Blitz with your code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stack-overflow-45945305).

Comment: Ok, I fixed the error by using `ng-template` and `let-i=index`. But now I'm facing another error saying "ERROR TypeError: el.setAttribute is not a function" - this is because I didn't defer the setter method to `AfterViewInit` event: Do I have use an EventEmitter, in order to accomplish that?

Comment: I think the simplest way to go is to wrap the renderer call inside a `setTimeout`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you hope to achieve with EventEmitter here. I suggest opening a new question since I think the above answer properly answers "why is index not set". Using `setTimeout` all over the place is not a good place. Using it here and there when doing some advanced things, and properly encapsulating those calls -- nothing bad with that.

Comment: Okay, maybe this is not the right place to ask about the eventemitter issue. But, setTimeout depends on the time set, rather than the synchronization: so using it would be wrong.

Comment: Using a `setTimeout` without the second argument means `0`, which means "the next possible asynchronous moment". Check out what is event loop in JavaScript to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Ok seems interesting .. But what if the next possible async event was even fired from another component or directive? Wouldn't it cause the execution of `this.renderer.setAttribute` to happen before `createEmbeddedView` operation has been done?